# How to generate multiple authors with multiple institutions in ACM style

Tags: titles, acm

The default ACM style looks like this
[image]

However, I need the style as follows. The `cls` of the template can be found [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACM templates present the authors in columns. If you want to display the author information in a single row instead multiple columns, you can: (1) use other latex commands along the defined in the template or (2) use another template.

- You can use the `\author{...}` command but including a single line of text or a  table, instead of using multiple `\alignauthor` to create new columns.

  ```
  \numberofauthors{1}
  \author{
    \alignauthor 
      XXX, YYY, ZZZ \\                       % names
      \affaddr{XXX, YYY, ZZZ } \\            % affiliations
      \email{XXX}, \email{yyy}, \email{zzz}  % emails
  }
  ```
- You can see an example of a table inside an `\author{...}` in [another question in stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271627/shared-author-affiliation-in-acm-sig-proc). They use a `tabular` in the `\author` to create a single line for shared affiliations.
- You can use another template. The sample you provided has an author block similar to the used in the [IEEE templates](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html).