# Shared author affiliation in ACM Sig-proc

Tags: author-number, acm, affiliation

I had a paper in IEEE format, that was using `\IEEEauthorblockN` and `\IEEEauthorblockA` for shared affiliation, nicely as shown below. Now I need to change the format to ACM. How can I do the same thing to ACM Sig-proc format?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{sig-alternate}
%...
\newcommand{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}
\def\sharedaffiliation{\end{tabular}\newline\begin{tabular}{c}}

\def\wu{\superscript{*}}
\def\wg{\superscript{\dag}}
%.... later
    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{aa\wu, bb\wu, cc\wu, dd\wu\wg, ff\wu}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{
    %  \sharedaffiliation
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \wu Department of Computer Science & & \wg Department of Surgery \\
        University         & & Hospital \\
      \end{tabular}
      ~\\
    Email: \{aa,bb,cc,dd,ff\}@university.edu}
    }
```

Comment: Please, make a full example showing also the document class you're loading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Insert this piece of coding just before the

```
\begin{document}
```

like so...

```
%
\def\sharedaffiliation{%
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}}
%
\begin{document}
```

and then adjust your particular 'author block' like so (example shown for 3 authors)...

```
\title{Alternate {\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX
Format\titlenote{(Produces...}}

\numberofauthors{3}
% Three authors sharing the same affiliation.
    \author{
      \alignauthor Ben King\\      
      \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
      \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
      \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}  \\
      \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
      \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }
          }
%
\maketitle
```

When compiled/previewed/rendered, this is the effect:
[image]

(Source: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a17)

Comment: is there a way to double this up, to get 6 authors? when I try it the result ends up skewed.

Comment: Is there a way to add superscript (if more than one affiliation, and some authors share one affiliation, then we need numbers on top of names and before the affiliation). But do not know how to do this in ACM template.