# 6 authors, groups of 3 for a shared affiliation in ACM Sig-proc

Tags: acm

I must create a paper with 6 authors in total the first three share one affiliation, and likewise the second three share a common affiliation.

In accordance with the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271627/shared-author-affiliation-in-acm-sig-proc) I've been attempting to render it in an aesthetically appealing way, using this code:

```
    \numberofauthors{6} %  in this sample file, there are a *total*
    % of EIGHT authors. SIX appear on the 'first-page' (for formatting
    % reasons) and the remaining two appear in the \additionalauthors section.



    \author{
          \alignauthor Ben King\\      
          \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
    %
          \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
          \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
    %
          \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
          \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
    %
          \sharedaffiliation
          \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}  \\
          \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
          \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 } \\
    % 
          \alignauthor Ben King\\      
          \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
    %
          \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
          \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
    %
          \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
          \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
    %
          \sharedaffiliation
          \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}  \\
          \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
          \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }
    }
```

However as you can see in the photo below the result is quite a mess.

How can I create this in an orderly way? i.e. well aligned and centred.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this

```
\def\sharedaffiliation{%
\end{tabular}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}}
```

for this

```
\def\sharedaffiliation{%
\end{tabular}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}\centering}
```

Solved the problem for me, for the second row of authors.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}







%\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{%times,
            paralist,
            graphicx,
            comment,
            verbatim,
            color,
%
            tikz,
            calc,
            multirow
}
%\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}% or will mess up captioning...
%\usepackage{svg}%needs to come after subfig
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={},
  pdfauthor={},
  pdfkeywords={},
  pageanchor=false,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  breaklinks=true,
}

\graphicspath{{figs/}}


\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\mailsa}\path|{english,sibarani,scerri}@iai.uni-bonn.de|  
\urldef{\mailsb}\path|{g.buscher,f.bensberg}@hs-osnabrueck.de|    
\urldef{\mailsc}\path|aba-sah.dadzie@open.ac.uk|   

\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}

\newcommand{\etal}{~{\em et\,al.,}\,}
\newcommand{\saro}{{\em \sc the TSAR Ontology}}%only one of the styling command obeyed :S

\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 







\def\sharedaffiliation{%
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}}
%
\begin{document}
%
% --- Author Metadata here ---
\conferenceinfo{SEMANTiCS '16,}{September 12-15^{th} Leipzig, Germany}
%\CopyrightYear{2007} % Allows default copyright year (20XX) to be over-ridden - IF NEED BE.
%\crdata{0-12345-67-8/90/01}  % Allows default copyright data (0-89791-88-6/97/05) to be over-ridden - IF NEED BE.
% --- End of Author Metadata ---

\title{{\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX
Format\titlenote{(Produces the permission block, and
copyright information). For use with
SIG-ALTERNATE.CLS. Supported by ACM.}}


\title{Block Chain Technologies \& the Semantic Web: \\A Study in Symbiosis}

\numberofauthors{6} 
\author{
      \alignauthor S. Matthew English\\      
      \email{english@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \alignauthor Elisa M. Sibarani\\     
      \email{sibarani@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \alignauthor Simon Scerri\\    
      \email{scerri@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"at Bonn}  \\
      \affaddr{Fraunhofer-Institut f\"ur Intelligente Analyse und Informationssysteme IAIS}   \\
      \affaddr{Germany}
%
\and % go to new row
%
      \alignauthor Elisa M. Sibarani\\     
      \email{sibarani@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \alignauthor S. Matthew English\\      
      \email{english@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \alignauthor Simon Scerri\\    
      \email{scerri@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"at Bonn}  \\
      \affaddr{Fraunhofer-Institut f\"ur Intelligente Analyse und Informationssysteme IAIS}   \\
      \affaddr{Germany}
}


\date{30 July 1999}
% Just remember to make sure that the TOTAL number of authors
% is the number that will appear on the first page PLUS the
% number that will appear in the \additionalauthors section.

\maketitle
```