# acmart: Multiple authors: all with same affiliation, one author an additional affiliation

Tags: titlesec, affiliation, author

I'm using "acmart" as the template. We have three authors, all from the same university but one of the authors also affiliated with an institute. I'm aware of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381530/multiple-authors-with-different-primary-affiliation-but-same-additional-affilia) question, however, its compiled version generates affiliation/email blocks redundantly.

My current version is like this:

```
\author{Naghi Mamuli$^*$,\hspace{1em} Arastoo Amel$^{*\mathsection}$,\hspace{1em} Homa Saadat$^*$ }
\affiliation{%
 \vspace{-1em}\institution{Aliabad State University$^*$ \hspace{0.3em} North Laboratory$^\mathsection$}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{\{naghi,\hspace{0.2em}arastoo,\hspace{0.2em}homa\}@aliabad.ac.ir}
}
```

That is compiled as:

[image]

As you can see, each of authors, affiliations, emails gets only one single line.

This is fine until we want to add ACM Reference Format:

[image]

As you can see, the marks (e.g *) that I have used to associate affiliations, now are visible in the "ACM Reference Format" since it is created automatically from the author names.

Is there any way that I can use "marks" but remove them in "ACM Reference Format"? or change this code to compile concisely like this one but without any problem in "ACM Reference Format"?

Answer (score 12):

The ACM Template discourages the use of a single `\author{}` for multiple authors.

- The [Quick and Dirty Manual](http://buildsys.acm.org/2017/resources/documents/HowTo.pdf) mentions explicitly that the template
  discourages the use of a "merged block" for authors.
- The [recommended practice](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/latex-best-practices) is to code all the authors in individual `\author{}`, `\affiliation{}` and `\email{}` commands. An example similar to your listing is marked as a wrong code.
- According to the [manual](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/acmart.pdf) (pages 8-12), the template have been designed to provide metadata for each author to the existing extraction tools. Therefore, these tools cannot determine multiple authors if you use only a single `\author{}` command.
- There is a [closed bug report in the acmart Github repository](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/98) that explains all.
- There is [an answer (here at StackExchange)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349706/72190) of the template author explaining it.

---

### Solution proposed in the manual

The manual suggests a solution where each author has an independent `\author{}` command and a shared `\affiliation{}`. Using this solution, the names of the authors will be presented one above the other and a single affiliation is presented below.

The example code (in the template download and at page 10 of the manual) is

```
\author{Ben Trovato}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}
```

The resulting block is like the following:

### [image]

### Other solution: Omit the reference block

However, if you wanna create a single author block, you may check other [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349672/how-to-write-names-of-multiple-authors-with-shared-affiliation-in-acm-2017-templ) at StackExchange.

- You can instruct the template to omit the ACM reference block using `\settopmatter{printacmref=false}`  before `\maketitle`

Comment: The downside of the solution proposed by the manual is that it pushes the email addresses above the institution. A common convention is to combine the email addresses (especially if they are at the same domain), e.g., `{ben,lars}@institution.edu` but doing so with the ACM template would probably lose the metadata.

Comment: What if the 1st and 3rd authors are at the same institution but not the 2nd?